# merging huge data files in R (used for searching)

Tags: r, database, bigdata, rsqlite

I am working in `R 3.5` and need to create a huge database of around 200 million rows and then search a file with around 15 million rows in that data base to find the reference value (and then cbind the two files: input file + matched file).

For smaller database files (~10 million rows) I used the `merge()` function to merge the input file with the database file. But, this is almost impossible now.

I tried `rsqlite` package and although it did work I did not like it.

pros

- reference data file is not loaded at first
- it does not need any installation (rather than `rsqlite` package)

cons

- it is very very slow (even after creating index on tables)
- the database file is huge (around 10Gb)
- binding the input file and found items is not simple (row number may be different)

I don't want to use SQL server or MySQL , because they both need installation and configuration and it is not suitable for all systems and servers.

any suggestions or similar experiences on big data matching?

Comment: The H2 database, an SQL database, is included right in the RH2 driver package, just as SQLite is included in RSQLite.  It does require that Java be installed but that is trivial.

Comment: You don't mention postgres or others, is it in general that you don't want to deal with a large server installation? If so, then know that I set up servers all the time with a single command: `docker run -d -p "5432:5432" --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres:10`. That's all the "server configuration" I have to do, everything else is table generation, indices, and data-input. I used [docker/postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) as an example, but [sqlserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) and others work equally easily.

Comment: You don't mention OS, but this works for me on win10 and ubuntu. The biggest kicker on windows is, especially for as much data as you have, you'll need to configure [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) to give it more system RAM (it is a little limiting in that what memory you give docker is taken from all of Windows ...). I have played with the windows-native postgres, too, equally straight-forward to configure. (I believe MariaDB and others have similar windows-native servers, perhaps better for RAM for you.)

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck; is H2 more efficient than SQLite? I always thought they are the same and only depends on user's experience to select one.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, but I have no experience in postgre. I am writing a R package for non-technical users and they should be able to run it on their PC or institutional server. So, preparing a DBMS, importing the database, connection string ... are major drawbacks. also, it should be OS-independent. So, my priority was file databases but SQLite was not satisfying.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant enough, but Microsoft has created an R version (MRAN: https://mran.microsoft.com/open) that allows for much faster computations in R (utilizing multithread libraries). Not sure if SQL is part of their package production, but might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Alirezaaa, You will need to benchmark them with your specific problem.  Also, how you use the backends makes a difference. Use of indexes and other features can affect the performance.

Comment: Pick two from: portable/user-friendly, fast, and free ... I agree that `sqlite` and therefore `RSQLite` are going to be your best storage given those constraints. Perhaps *"very very slow"* means you should be looking at your queries to optimize their performance.